# How do I create a windows shorcut for running a perl script?

Tags: windows

How can I launch ms-dos and a perl script using a shortcut?

I tried to use .bat file with:

```
perl C:\script.pl
```

That didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure perl is in the system path, and it should work.